# Is it possible to create a new Gremlin Graph DB and Graph using c# code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have a Azure Cosmos DB account with Gremlin API. I'm using Gremlin.Net to query the db.

var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer(hostname, port, enableSsl: true, username: "/dbs/" + database + "/colls/" + collectionName, password: authKey);

username parameter takes dbname and collection name.

Just wondering how to create a new graph db and a graph under the account using c# code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched the [azure gremlin .Net source code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-gremlindotnet-getting-started) , no such methods like creating database or graph could be found. There is an statement mentioned in above link：

> This sample uses the open-source Gremlin.Net driver to connect to an
>   Azure Cosmos DB Graph API account and run some basic Create, Read,
>   Update, Delete Gremlin queries.

It seems that we could only execute gremlin queries, can't CRUD database itself.

I also searched [Cosmos DB REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/), no such special api for CRUD cosmos db graph api. Only operations of database and collection could be found. So I tested it with below sample code with [Document DB .Net SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-dotnet#add-sample-data) and it works for me.

```
client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authKey"]);
await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = "db"});
await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
    UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(DatabaseId),
    new DocumentCollection
        {
           Id = "coll"
        },
    new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 400 });
```

I know it is strange(there is no collection in cosmos db graph api,it supposed to be graph) but it works for me.You could try it on your side.

[image]

Hope it helps you.